# iPad enter passcode view

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, uiviewcontroller

Is there a Enter Passcode view controller for iPad? You know, the one which shows up when you have passcode enabled on iPad...This is how it looks like:
[image]
Thanks.

Comment: There is no built-in UI component for this.  You can search for a third party implementation, but I doubt that one exists.

Comment: Why not create your own?

Answer (score 2):

u can use in ipad

https://github.com/lashad/PTPasscodeViewController

Comment: This doesn't quite look like what he is looking for.

Comment: This is also GPLed, so unless your app is also GPLed you cannot.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a free (BSD) passcode control that works on both iPhone and iPad:

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/bzpasscodeviewcontroller

I'm just starting with it myself, will update with any important tips/notes I discover.

Comment: So far I'm pleased with it for my purposes, give it a shot!